# Control web app with key-presses when browser isn't "in the front"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

Like the topic says, I'm wondering if it's possible to control my web application even when I have other applications in front on the browser?

Pref. using javascript!

Thanks!

Comment: If you're IE you can: http://www.spider.io/blog/2012/12/internet-explorer-data-leakage/.  But, seriously, no.  This would be a huge security hole.  How would the computer know whether to send the key press to your website or to another app?  What if I was typing in a password into another program, I don't want your site to be able to read that!

Comment: doesn't this open keylogging issues?

Comment: @user2264587: Yes.  That's why it's impossible :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Imagine the tremendous security vulnerability this would expose. Do you want a web page running in your minimized browser to read the letter you're typing in your word processor?

Furthermore,  such a mechanism would be problematic from a purely technical perspective. If you have multiple browser windows open, which one should "get" the keystrokes? If the answer is "all of them", that could be quite bad if a command intended for one particular open browser instance went to all of them. (For instance, in one open Web application, `Ctrl+N` skips to the next song, but in another, `Ctrl+N` creates a new document. If you have both pages open, such a capturing mechanism would perform both actions!)

Granted, such function *could* possibly be safely implemented with user consent (compare to microphone input from `getUserMedia` -- it's not exactly eavesdropping if you clicked "Allow"), but there is currently no API or specification that would allow for such functionality.